# In a XAML winrt app, is it possible to apply the dark theme to just one element?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm using the player framework media player and I've got it against a black background, but the app uses the light theme.  I would like to apply the dark theme to just this one element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible right now in WinRT. In case of Black background in light theme, you have to define your own styles and merge it in particular container's resources (in your case it is Gird).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can place the element in a Grid and set the Grid' background to black.  This will effectively always make it so that the background of the element is black even if the "light" theme is applied.

Comment: I've already got it in a black background, the problem is that the elements are designed for a white background.  For example.  The play button should be a white circle with a white "play" symbol, instead it's a white (filled) circle with a black "play" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked if it would work, but you could try including the dark theme resource dictionary that should be somewhere in (or near) "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design" in your project and setting it as a merged dictionary for the Grid. Perhaps that would override the light theme dictionary you have otherwise set for the rest of the application.

The alternative is to modify the templates for all the controls used in the media player to match their dark theme versions. Blend might be really helpful there since you could open two instances of Blend and easily compare the colors used in a baseline dark theme version of the control and your custom dark theme versions.